# Active Directory Merge - Merging User accounts

Tags: windows, migration, directory, admt

I need to merge two active directories, OLD and NEW.

However, many users already exist in both OLD and NEW with the same userid.

I want to preserve the sid of Bill@new, while merging in the sid history of Bill@old.  How do I tell ADMT to not create a new account but rather merge with the existing 'new' account?

Erick

Answer (score 1):

There is a section near the end of the user migration wizard in which you can tell ADMT to merge objects. There, select the "Migrate and Merge Conflicting Objects". You will also want to make sure that the "Migrate user SIDs to target domain" option is checked.  This will ensure that the source user SID is copied to the SID history of the target user.